# Knockout JS make only one property of a complex array of objects observable

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, knockout.js

I'm building an observableArray from a server call (C#) using $.getJson. My array is built from a list of complex objects. The complex object has simple properties and array properties. I only want to make one of the properties (a boolean) of my objects observable, but I still want to be able to access the other properties from the UI (however the other properties wont change so I dont want them observables).  Currently I'm just populating my observableArray from the data I get from the server. Is there a way to just create an observable of that one property???

```
function viewModel()
{
        var self = this;
        self.documents = ko.observableArray();

        $.getJSON("/getdocuments", function (data) {
            return self.documents(data);
        });

}

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: Yeah, just have the one property be an observable. Without any code, it's hard to be more specific than that.

Comment: I just posted how I'm creating my array. I dont see where can I set one of its properties to be an observable

Comment: Right now, none of your properties are observables. Just loop through the `data` array and add an observable and set it to whatever property you want. Or, use the mapping plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

1. Add individual object constructor function that will build each of your objects with observable property you need:

   ```
   var ObjectModel = function(config) {
       this.prop1 = config.prop1;
       ...
       this.propO = ko.observable(config.propO);
   }
   ```
2. in you success ajax callback iterate object configs you get and feed them to that object constructor, then add to array in your main viewmodel:

   ```
   $.getJSON("/getdocuments", function (data) {
       var arr = [];

       data.forEach(function(objectCfg){
           arr.push( new ObjectModel(objectCfg) );
       })
       self.documents( arr );
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you that pointed me to the right direction. I did exactly as you said except that I created a function to just add my observable.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Nikolay said, except I used this function as a pipeline for my array.

```
var addProperty = function(inObject)
{
    inObject.IsFav = ko.observable(inObject.IsFavorite);
    return inObject;
}


$.getJSON("/getdocuments", function (data) {
var arr = [];

data.forEach(function(objectCfg){
    arr.push( addProperty(objectCfg) );
})
self.documents( arr );
```

}